# Which is rootsite, sitecollection, WebApplication and subsite in the following URL..?

Tags: url

```
http://sp13dev:45555/sites/PranavB/Team_Site/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/
```

Above is the SharePoint URL, and I want to know which is what?
I am totally confused

i.e RootSite, Site Collection, WebApplication and SubSite..etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the url given url, these are :

```
RootSite - **PranavB**  Url:  http://sp13dev:45555/sites/PranavB

Site Collection -  **PranavB** Url: http://sp13dev:45555/sites/PranavB

WebApplication  - http://sp13dev:45555/

SubSite - **Team_Site**  URl: http://sp13dev:45555/sites/PranavB/Team_Site/
```

Comment: So..u mean to say that Site Collection and RootSite are always same??

Comment: A site collection is just a container for a collection of web sites. So the site at the root is called Root Site.

Comment: For more clarifications: http://omicron-llama.co.uk/2012/02/13/what-the-hell-is-a-sharepoint-site-collection/

Comment: Thank you..:) I am a fresher/beginner of Sharepoint....just want to know scope in the future of SP.

Comment: As per i know web application is deployed on Farm...so we cannot see farm name in URL?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115723/retrieve-single-field-using-caml-query-in-sharepoint-using-javascript